# Call paint event from mouse move event

Tags: c#, winforms, paint

When mouse move over a panel2, I need to draw lines. So far I have done following

```
public Form1()
{           
    InitializeComponent();            

}

private void panel2_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (isDragging)
    {
        letsPaint(sender, e);
    }
}

private void panel2_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (isDragging) 
    {
        mouseMoveX = e.X;
        mouseMoveY = e.Y;                               
        this.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(panel2_Paint);
    }
}

private void letsPaint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) 
{             
    Pen blackpen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3);
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    g.DrawLine(blackpen, mouseClickedX, mouseClickedY, mouseMoveX, mouseMoveY);
    g.Dispose(); 
}
```

But nothing happens when I move mouse. I think I did something wrong PaintEventHandler() here. Please tell me how to do this and also if there is any better way for this.

Also I think my method will drawline on the form but I need to draw line on the panel2. How to do?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You invalidate:

```
public Form1()
{           
  InitializeComponent();            
  panel2.Paint += new letsPaint;
}

private void panel2_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  if (isDragging) {
    mouseMoveX = e.X;
    mouseMoveY = e.Y;                               
    panel2.Invalidate();
  }
}
```

and you don't dispose the graphic object (you didn't create it), but you do the pen:

```
private void letsPaint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {             
  using (Pen blackpen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3)) {
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(blackpen, 
                        mouseClickedX, mouseClickedY, mouseMoveX, mouseMoveY);
  }
}
```

---

Here is a quick little method that works with a bitmap:

```
Bitmap bmp;
Point lastPoint;

public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();
  bmp = new Bitmap(panel1.ClientSize.Width, panel1.ClientSize.Height, 
                   System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);

  panel1.MouseDown += panel1_MouseDown;
  panel1.MouseMove += panel1_MouseMove;
  panel1.Paint += panel1_Paint;
}

void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
  e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, Point.Empty);
}

void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
  if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left) {
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)) {
      g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, lastPoint, e.Location);
    }
    lastPoint = e.Location;
    panel1.Invalidate();
  }
}

void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
  lastPoint = e.Location;
}
```

This will flicker, so you would want to replace your panel with a double-buffered panel.  Something like this:

```
public class PanelEx : Panel {
  public PanelEx() {
    this.DoubleBuffered = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: I think my method will drawline on the form but I need to draw line on the panel2

Comment: @user1478137 Updated, but you are only drawing a point really.  You need to store the points in a list or draw in a bitmap and then draw the bitmap in that paint event.

Comment: everything is working as I wanted but the problem is after drawing a line when I try to draw another line previous line is removed. But I don't want to remove the previous line. I want to keep all the lines that are drawn. How can I do this?

Comment: @user1478137 That was the point of my previous comment.  You need to store the points then loop through them in the paint event, or draw your lines into a bitmap and just display the image in the paint event.

Comment: Can you give me any link/resource for this?

Comment: @user1478137 Updated with an example.